# Bash script to print pattern 1, search and print all lines from pattern 2 through Pattern 3, and print pattern 4

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

Please Help - I'm very rusty with my sed/awk/grep and I'm attempting to process a file (an export of a PDF that is around 4700 pages long).

Here is what I'm attempting to do: search/print line matching pattern 1,  search for line matching pattern 2 and print that line and all lines from it until pattern 3 (if it includes/prints the line with pattern 3, I'm ok with it at this point), and search/print lines matching pattern 4.

All of the above patterns should occur in order (pattern 1,2,3,4) several hundred times in the file and I need to keep them in order.

Pattern 1: lines beginning with 1-5 and a whitespace (this is specific enough despite it seeming vague)
Pattern 2: lines beginning with (all caps) SOLUTION:
Pattern 3: lines beginning with (all caps) COMPLIANCE:
Pattern 4: lines beginning with an IP Addresses

Here's what I've cobbled together, but it's clearly not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
sed '

/^[1-5]\s/p {

       /^SOLUTION/,/^COMPLIANCE/p {

                /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/p }

}' sample.txt
```

Comment: Add a few lines from `sample.txt` to your question.

Comment: grep is for finding an RE in a file and printing the matching line. sed is for making simple substitutions on individual lines in a file. For anything else you should just be using awk. Post some sample input and expected output and we can help you. What if, for example you hit 2 lines that begin with digits 1-5 and a white space before the first line that starts with SOLUTION? Do you ignore the first one or what? Finding the lines that match is always trivial, it's handling the similar-looking lines that don't match that's complicated so create your sample input to show THAT.

Answer (score 1):

to use `p` in sed you need to use `-n` as well and also add `-r` for extended regex:

Here is how it should look like:

```
sed -r -n '{
/^[1-5] /p
/^SOLUTION/,/^COMPLIANCE/p
/^([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/p
}' sample.txt
```

Comment: I literally just got it to work, but I actually like your IP address method better.

Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Won't that print lines that match each condition regardless of the order in which the conditions are satisfied?

Comment: No, he specifically said `All of the above patterns should occur in order (pattern 1,2,3,4) several hundred times in the file and I need to keep them in order.`.

Comment: @EdMorton ok, but what is the actual difference in his case? If line starts from digit and space it can not match any other pattern. So in my case we just print pattern 1 matches, then pattern 2 to 3 matches amd then pattern 4 matches.

Comment: Imagine he has 2 lines in his file that start with a digit in the range 1-5 followed by a space before the first line that starts with SOLUTION. Your script will print both but I would expect he'd really only want the 2nd one since it's part of the sequence he needs while the first one is not. What if SOLUTION occurs twice before COMPLIANCE? There are MANY other ways in which this could fail. The OP hasn't told us how to handle any of them yet but just printing every matching line regardless of context seems clearly not to be what he's asked for so far.

Comment: @EdMorton I can easely fix all these conditions but i need to know what he wants exactly, it hasn't been described in-depth in his question.

Comment: Right, that's why I've posted a comment under his question asking for more information and an example showing how he wants to handle the interesting issues.

Comment: @EdMorton i actually just fixed what he had, so it started to work and changed a little bit his ip address pattern :)

Comment: Understood but that's the tiniest tip of the iceberg and I suspect the OP just hasn't really thought through the rainy day scenarios yet.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this, untested since you didn't provide any sample input or expected output:

```
awk '
BEGIN         { state = 0 }
/^[1-5] /     { if (state ~ /[01]/) { block = $0; state = 1 } }
/^SOLUTION/   { state = (state ~ /[12]/ ? 2 : 0) }
state == 2    { block = block ORS $0 }
/^COMPLIANCE/ { state = (state == 2 ? 3 : state) }
/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/ { if (state == 3) { print block ORS $0; state = 0 } }
' file
```